# Remove Disk from Primordial Storage Pool?

Tags: windows-server-2016, storage-spaces

I am a little stuck here. Setting up a new server (for storage spaces) one of the disks we wanted to use for other purposes got pulled into the primordial storage pool. Somehow I see no option to remove it. There seems to be no way to change the CanPool attribute on the disk.

It does not show up under get-disk, and under get-physicaldisk it is marked with "CanPool true".

How do I remove it from the primordial pool so I can format as basic disc?

Comment: It seems we have the same problem.https://serverfault.com/questions/907948/reclaiming-disks-from-storage-spaces-direct Have you tried switching slots?

Comment: Can not do - in my case it grabbed the reserve boot disk which is a 128gb SataDOM (https://www.supermicro.com/products/nfo/SATADOM.cfm). I reinstalled (trial phase for the server) and plugged it with a partition, so storage spaces leaves it alone.

Comment: Whow. Put it in as answer and gets some points from me. That is the powershell cmd i was looking for.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/failoverclusters/set-clusterstoragespacesdirectdisk?view=win10-ps This worked for me. The disks showed up immediately.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some powershell commands which helped me through this.  The command Rikuto shared is part of the solution but I had to shutdown S2D in order for the command to work.

```
#find out the unique id for your disk (look for the disk you just created by size)
Get-PhysicalDisk | Select-Object -Property FriendlyName, uniqueID, Size

#assign the UID of the desired disk to a variable
$DiskUID = "<unique disk ID>"

#disable S2D so that disk can be freed from pool and set disk to not be claimed by pool
Disable-ClusterStorageSpacesDirect
Set-ClusterStorageSpacesDirectDisk -CanBeClaimed:$false -PhysicalDiskIds $DiskUID

#re-enable S2D and wait for your clustered volume to become healthy
Enable-ClusterStorageSpacesDirect
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: No need to Disable and then Enable the S2D. Just make sure you first remove the disk(s) from the S2D pool. Then run the Set-ClusterStorageSpacesDirectDisk and the disk will now show up as a standard disk in Disk Manager.

Comment: Just trying to remove the disk gives an error `Remove-PhysicalDisk : This operation is not supported on primordial storage pools.`  The Disable-ClusterStorageSpacesDirect` command is not available for me