# Reclaiming disks from storage spaces direct

Tags: storage-spaces

I removed the virtual disk and the storage pool entirely.
Even though the physical disks aren't attached to a pool anymore, windows doesn't reclaim them.

What I tried so far (in a different order every time):
Creating a new pool and deleting it again / Node reboots / Reset-PhysicalDisk / Set-PhysicalDisk -Usage Retired / Remove-PhysicalDisk / Restart entire cluster / Uninstall disks via device manager

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/failoverclusters/set-clusterstoragespacesdirectdisk?view=win10-ps

This worked for me. The disks showed up immediately.

Comment: I've faced such thing in my S2D cluster and this worked for me - https://argonsys.com/learn-microsoft-cloud/articles/clearing-disks-storage-spaces-direct/. Moreover, I faced a lot of issues with S2D in my configuration and I decided to move to other solution